# Azure TableServiceContext - Asynchronous AddObject Method?

Tags: azure-table-storage, tableservicescontext

Azure TableServiceContext exposes asynchronous alternatives for most of the crud options

Except the **AddObject Method**

Is there a reason for this strange ommision?

Answer (score 0):

AddObject is similar to DeleteObject and UpdateObject which all just changes the state of the TableServiceContext. Nothing is being sent to the server until you do SaveChanges so only SaveChanges really need to be asynchronous.